# how to: content tiles of varying sizes?

Tags: jquery, css

I've seen this technique used quite a bit ([pinterest.com](http://pinterest.com), [factorymagazine.com](http://factorymagazine.com)) where the content(or content excerpts) are displayed in tiles of varying sizes in a seemingly fluid manner. I'm wonder what this is called and how it's achieved. Thanks.

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for the [jQuery Masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/), this should cover all of your needs and is simple to use.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/9U9Zh/2/

jQuery:

```
$("#container").masonry();
```

If you would rather not use jQuery than there is [Vanilla Masonry](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/), a duplicate of jQuery Masonry except that it uses Vanilla JS only, usage is almost as simple as jQuery Masonry: `var wall = new Masonry(document.getElementById("container"));`